# Splitting a long phrase into an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, split

I need to take the phrase

It’s that time of year when you clean out your closets, dust off shelves, and spruce up your floors. Once you’ve taken care of the dust and dirt, what about some digital cleaning? Going through all your files and computers may seem like a daunting task, but we found ways to make the process fairly painless.

and upon pressing a button

split it into an array

iterate over that array at each step

Build SPAN elements as you go, along with the attributes

Add the SPAN elements to the original DIV

Add a click handler to the SPAN elements, or to the DIV, which causes the style on the SPAN to change on mouseover.

So far I had

```
function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
  var arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(separator);

  print('The original string is: "' + stringToSplit + '"');
  print('The separator is: "' + separator + '"');
  print("The array has " + arrayOfStrings.length + " elements: ");

  for (var i=0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++)
    print(arrayOfStrings[i] + " / ");
}

var space = " ";
var comma = ",";

splitString(tempestString, space);
splitString(tempestString);
splitString(monthString, comma);
for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{

}
var yourSpan = document.createElement('span');
yourSpan.innerHTML = "Hello";

var yourDiv = document.getElementById('divId');
yourDiv.appendChild(yourSpan);

yourSpan.onmouseover = function () {
    alert("On MouseOver");

}
```

and for html I have

```
The DIV that will serve as your input (and output) is here, with
        id="transcriptText":</p>
      <div id="transcriptText"> It’s that time of year when you clean out your
        closets, dust off shelves, and spruce up your floors. Once you’ve taken
        care of the dust and dirt, what about some digital cleaning? Going
        through all your files and computers may seem like a daunting task, but
        we found ways to make the process fairly painless.</div>
      <br>
      <div id="divideTranscript" class="button">&nbsp;Transform the
        Transcript!&nbsp; </div>
```

Any help on how to move one? I have been stuck for quite some time

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off this looks like homework.

That said, I'll try to help without giving you the actual code, since we're not supposed to give actual working solutions to homework.   You're splitting the string too many times (once is all that's needed based on the instructions you gave) and you have to actually store the result of the split call somewhere that your other code can use it.

Your instructions say to add attributes to the span, but not which attributes nor what their contents should be.

Your function should follow the instructions:

1) Split the string.  Since it doesn't specify on what, I'd assume words.  So split it on spaces only and leave the punctuation where it is.

2) with the array of words returned from the split() function, iterate over it like you attempt to, but *inside* the braces that scope the loop is where you want to concatenate the `<span>` starting and ending tags around the original word.

3) use the document.createElement() to make that current span into a DOM element.  Attach the mouseover and click handlers to it, then appendChild() it to the div.

add the handler to your button to call the above function.

Note that it's possibly more efficient to use the innerHTML() function to insert all the spans at once, but then you have to loop again to add the hover/click handlers.

Comment: so how do I edit it to split that entire phrase, I appreciate your help I am just extremely new to coding and although I understand most of what you are saying to do I am not sure hot to go about doing it.  Also do I add like span <span class="word" id="word0"> before every word?

Comment: splitting is done the way you're already doing it. If you want to split on each word without removing the punctuation, the most direct approach is just `phrase.split(' ')` (that's a space, to indicate that you're splitting on each space).  That fails if you have multiple spaces between words for any reason (well, doesn't fail but adds to the array spaces as well), though that seems OK for your purposes.  As for the class and id; it wasn't listed in your requirement but if you want to add them you can.